# Cgridview selected row column value in Yii

Tags: yii

[image]

Using below code im getting all "Name" Column values

```
$.fn.yiiGridView.getColumn("CGridViewUser",1).text();
```

if i want to get selected row "Name" column value (like shown in image), how to achevie this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First add an ID to your GridView.

```
   <?php
   $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array
   (
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'htmlOptions'=>array('id'=>'MyID'), //MyID is an ID to grid wrapper
         ........
         ........
```

Now, jQuery

```
       $("#MyID table tbody tr").click(function()
       {
            $this=$(this);
            var firstColVal= $this.find('td:first-child').text();
            var secondColVal= $this.find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
            var lastColVal= $this.find('td:last-child').text();
            alert(firstColVal);
       });
```

It will work.

Comment: awesome!!! got value from your code...Having another issue have to set the obtained value in a form's textbox, can you suggest how to do it?

Comment: Add a selector to your form Ex: i'm giving an ID `<input id='anID' type...`. Now `$("#anID").val(secondColVal);`

Comment: yes its working!!! i want to show the name column in textbox but in DB i have to save ID (see attached image)

Comment: instead of giving column number,is it possible to give column name?